# Bulk update strategy lucene?

Tags: lucene, updates, bulk

For a project I am working on, I have a index of nearly 10 million documents. For sets of documents, ranging from 100k to 5m, I need to regularly add fields.

Lucene 4 supports updating documents (basically remove and add). What would be a good approach to add the field to a larger set of documents?

What I have tried so far is using the `SearcherManager` to wrap a `IndexWriter`, and to make small searches for documents that do not yet contain the field, but do match the `Query` I am interested in, by wrapping these in a `BooleanQuery`. I then iterate over the `ScoreDocs`, retrieve the documents, add my new field and call `writer.updateDocument` with the `uuid` I stored with each document. Then I call `commit` and `maybeRefreshBlocking` , reacquire the `IndexSearcher` and search again. This is kinda slow and seems a naive approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to require the **IndexSearcher** before your searches will return different results based on the fields that you add.

In the case where your searches are never affected by the fields that you add, you only need to reacquire the **IndexSearcher** when documents are added to the index.

So, it will simplify and speed things up at least a little if you only reaquire the **IndexSearcher** when necessary rather than before each search.

Comment: Thanks Mark. For my case I think it needs to be re-acquired as I only want to process documents that do not have the extra field yet; the fastest(?) way to determine that was to search again.. I am wondering though what a 'correct' batchsize would be, as the more documents can be processed in a batch, the less overhead of searching, committing etc. there is.